# How can I make javascript sing?

Tags: javascript, audio, text-to-speech, webspeech-api

I saw that there's some singing voices in the Web Speech API using the voice "Good News" (and "Bad News"). But I'd like to know how I can make my own custom song. It seems to sing the same notes. Can I pass it what notes I'd like for each word?

edit: a comment below points out the "Good News" is a mac voice. So the below code might only work on Mac. I'm looking for a more generalized solution for both pc and mac.

```js
if (!window.speechSynthesis) {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support speechSynthesis !!");
}

var voices;
function loadVoices() {
    voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    if (voices.length == 0) alert("cannot get voices !!");
    console.log(voices.map(function (x) {return x.name;}));
}

var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la");

function sing(name) {
    speechSynthesis.cancel();
    loadVoices();
    msg.voice = voices[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < voices.length; i++)
    if (voices[i].name == name) msg.voice = voices[i];
    speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}

setTimeout(function() {
sing('Good News');
},1000); // let browser initialize for a sec
```

I noticed Web Speech api [has something called pitch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/pitch). But after messing with it, the word doesn't really "sing". You can see a [codepen here](https://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/wGzuJ). Also I don't think I could convert a frequency to a pitch, like for example Middle C is 261.6 Hz.

I also noticed another library called meSing.js but the voices sound too robotic:
http://usdivad.com/mesing/
I downloaded mesing.js from [github](https://github.com/usdivad/mesing), and I changed the hard coded voice that it uses to other voices that are given in the underlying voice library ([meSpeak.js](https://github.com/mikolalysenko/mespeak)), and even though the voice changes, it still sounds robotic.

I like the sound quality of the first "Good News" but I'd like to know how to make a custom one, is it possible?

edit: maybe I can take 'Good News' with just one word. and then play that with different pitch settings. I'd have to see what the range of pitches are. still experimenting..

Comment: interesting, i dont know that modern browsers have text-to-speech feature

Comment: @datdinhquoc welcome to 2020 baby!

Comment: ... That's just a macOs feature (like an old, very old one). Since immemorial times, you can [make your mac sing from terminal](https://www.google.com/search?q=make+your+mac+sing+from+terminal) and the two ones you mentioned are not the only singing voices, have a look in the *Novelty* subfolder of your available voices (SystemPrefs > Accessibility > Speech > System Voice >Customize), and try Bells, Cellos or Pipe Organ. So all in all, this question has nothing to do with webspeech-api. If you want to make your own, just learn how to make a TTS Voice.

Comment: What question should my answer be for? My comment points out that the question is motivated by a misconception and that it should not have been asked to begin with. It won't answer "how to make js sing" or whatever.